# Problems downloading files from ftp server to directory

Tags: python, download, ftp, directory, ftplib

I am trying to download files from an ftp server to a local folder. Below I have included my code, the script is able to access the ftp succesfully and list the names of the files on the ftp server however where my issue lies is I am not sure how to download them to a local directory.

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os, sys, os.path

def handleDownload(block):
    file.write(block)

ddir='U:/Test Folder'
os.chdir(ddir)
ftp = FTP('sidads.colorado.edu')
ftp.login()

print ('Logging in.')
directory = '/pub/DATASETS/NOAA/G02158/unmasked/2012/04_Apr/'

print ('Changing to ' + directory)
ftp.cwd(directory)
ftp.retrlines('LIST')

print ('Accessing files')

filenames = ftp.nlst() # get filenames within the directory
print (filenames)
```

I tried using the following code below however it gives me the error in the photo below.

```
for filename in filenames:
    if filename != '.':
        local_filename = os.path.join('U:/Test Folder/',                   filename)
    file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)
    file.close()
ftp.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: missing the error

Comment: Are you trying to write the downloaded files into a zip file? `local_filename` will end up being something like `'U:/Test Folder/New WinZip File.zip/filename.txt` which is probably not what you want. Also you need to indent the next 3 lines to be inside the `if` statement.

Comment: well. It seems you got an permission denied.
You wouldnt have to take a picture. The relevant info is in the bottom. 
Errno 13 'C:/ArcGis/New folder\\.'

The filename seems odd.

Comment: Yes Martin Evans I am trying to write all the zip files in the ftp server to the folder but am struggling to figure out how.

Comment: are you able to download files normally?

Comment: If you want to zip the files have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for filename in filenames:
    if filename not in ['.', '..']:
        local_filename = os.path.join(ddir, filename)

        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f_output:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, f_output.write)

ftp.quit()
```

Your code was still attempting to download `.` filenames. You need to indent the writing of the valid filenames. Also by using `with` it will close the file automatically.

Comment: When I ran this I didn't get the permission error like before how ever I did receive the error MESSAGE OS error Errno 22 invalid argument python Line 28

Comment: You'll have to tell me which is line 22 in your script.

Comment: Sorry line 28 is         with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f_output:

Comment: What exact version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am running python version 3.6.0

Comment: I suggest you try adding `print(local_filename)` to make sure it is valid. I have updated it to skip `..` also just in case.

Comment: The updated .. is what got it to work, was able to download all files to the directory. Thank you for your help!